# How to call a function whenever a key is pressed in python

Tags: python

I have a program that is running a loop.
Whenever I press, for example, the key "ESC" on keyboard, it should call out a function which prints "You pressed the key ESC" and maybe executes some commands too.

I tried this:

```
from msvcrt import getch

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 27: #ESC
        print("You pressed ESC")
    elif key == 13: #Enter
        print("You pressed key ENTER")
        functionThatTerminatesTheLoop()
```

After all my tries, msvcrt doesnt seem to work in python 3.3 or for whatever other reason.
Basically, how do I make my program react to any keypress at any point of the time while the program is running?

EDIT: Also, I found this:

```
import sys

while True:
    char = sys.stdin.read(1)
    print ("You pressed: "+char)
    char = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

But it requires enter to be entered into the command console for the input to be reistered, but I have my loop running in a tkinter, so I still need a way for it to do something immediately after the keypress is detected.

Comment: I think you mean that it doesn't work in IDLE (or possibly another IDE). However, the basic idea (e.g. the part up to the `elif` statement) works perfectly, for me at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your program uses the `tkinter` module, binding is very easy.
You don't need any external modules like `PyHook`.

For example:

```
from tkinter import * #imports everything from the tkinter library

def confirm(event=None): #set event to None to take the key argument from .bind
    print('Function successfully called!') #this will output in the shell

master = Tk() #creates our window

option1 = Button(master, text = 'Press Return', command = confirm)
option1.pack() #the past 2 lines define our button and make it visible

master.bind('<Return>', confirm) #binds 'return' to the confirm function
```

Unfortunately, this will only work in a `Tk()` window. Also, when applying the callback during the key binding, you can't specify any arguments.

As a further explanation of `event=None`, we put it in because `master.bind` annoyingly sends the key as an argument. This is is fixed by putting `event` as the parameter in the function. We then set `event` to the default value `None` because we have a button that uses the same callback, and if it wasn't there we would get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this wasn't what I was exactly looking for, but it helped me find my mistake. I used .tag_bind(), and those only work with oriented objects, I tried using .bind and it works perfectly :) I can now give commands with any keypress at any time and nothing needs to be even focused etc. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for non-Window based library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/.